# How to disable TLS Renegotation in ElasticBeanstalk AWS for Linux AMI?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It is a security best practice to disable TLS Renegotiation in production.
What is the best way to do this in an Apache2-based **Elastic Beanstalk Deployment (Python/Django)?**

Answer (score 0):

To disable TLS Renegotiation in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for Linux AMI, you can modify the Apache configuration file. Here's the steps:

Step 1 : Connect to your EC2 instance using SSH.

Step 2 : Open the Apache configuration file using a text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

Step 3 : Add the following line to the end of the file:

```
SSLInsecureRenegotiation off
```

Step 4 : Save and close the file.

Step 5 : Restart Apache to apply the changes by typing:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: Well my question was more around EB based deployment.

Comment: Try this @AniketMaithani

Create a file named .ebextensions/httpd-ssl.config in your application source code.

files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      SSLHonorCipherOrder on
      SSLInsecureRenegotiation off